# Complex exponentials inequality series proof disc

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z$ is in a closed disc $\bar{D}(0;1)$, how do we prove that $(3-e)|z|\leq |e^z-1| \leq (e-1)|z|$ ?

I could attempt: $(3-\sum \frac{1}{n!})|z| \leq  |\sum \frac{z^n}{n!} -1| \leq  (\sum \frac{1}{n!}-1)|z|$, but I'm stuck...

Comment: I think you should write out the terms first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RHS

\begin{align}
\left |  \left (1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \dots \right ) -1\right | &= \left | z \left( 1 + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^2}{3!} + \dots \right ) \right |  \\
&\leq |z|\left | \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!} \right | \\
&\color{green}{\leq |z|\left | \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \right | }\\
&= |z|\left | e^z -1 \right |
\end{align}
LHS

I believe we get $|z|  \leq |1 - e^z|$ via minimum principle using $g(z) = \frac{|1 - e^z|}{|z|}$ which has a removable singularity at $z = 0$. Multiplying both sides by $3 - e$ completes the LHS. (gotta eat, will check later.)

Comment: thanks !...filling spaces...

Comment: I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious but $2-(e^z-1)=3-e^z$. How did you get equality in the third line?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski, I made a misprint, because I was supposed to prove for $e$, not $e^z$.

Comment: OK. I'm still not understanding how you derive line 3 from line 2.

Comment: No, it's a mistake. Let me try to fix.

Comment: I will return to check my mistake, but i have to eat now.